# Selecting <td>'s over several rows and even tables with jquery

Tags: jquery, calendar

I'm trying to build a **selectable calendar** that show's me some kind of availability.
My first attempt worked great. I just used rows to show me a date and I could easily use nextUntil - but it got a little more complicating after breaking it down into several tables each representing a month.

Now my problem is that I can only select the `<td>`'s from one row at a time and I can't think of a way to go to the next row without shredding my `until` statement.
It is very important, that a "booked" class would stop my tool from selecting a td beyond that point.

I hope my question came out kinda clear since english is not my mother tongue.

Thanks a lot to everyone for at least reading through it :D

Now here's the code so far: [In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ricktap/MEeXV/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/MEeXV/8/

Cleaned up things a lot.  Make sure to cache your selectors if you are going to use them again.
I also switched to a delegated event for the click handler.

Now when you click on a day it takes the list of all the days and then uses `indexes` to find all the next and previous days. It make sure to stop when it hits a `booked` day.

The click handler could probably be split up to make the code cleaner and DRYer, but this will get you on your way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I started working on an answer yesterday, but I think yours is better than mine would have been.